# WPF ControlTemplate use/show default style of a PART_

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is a general WPF question, but I'll illustrate with something I'm working on.

I'm making a verticalscrollbar that shows some extra data. Currently my way of working is defining a ControlTemplate and  using the default control template styles of msdn and modifying these.

Like this:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar"
                 TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
      <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.RowSpan="3"
            CornerRadius="2"
            Background="#F0F0F0" />
    <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0"
                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                  Height="18"
                  Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand"
                  Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" />
    <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
           Grid.Row="1"
           IsDirectionReversed="true">
      <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                      Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
      </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
      <Track.Thumb>
        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"
               Margin="1,0,1,0">
          <Thumb.BorderBrush>

            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                 EndPoint="1,0">
              <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                                Offset="0.0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                                Offset="1.0" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
              </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

          </Thumb.BorderBrush>
          <Thumb.Background>

            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                 EndPoint="1,0">
              <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                                Offset="0.0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                                Offset="1.0" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
              </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

          </Thumb.Background>
        </Thumb>
      </Track.Thumb>
      <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                      Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
      </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
    </Track>
    <RepeatButton Grid.Row="3"
                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                  Height="18"
                  Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand"
                  Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now as you can see, this is a lot of code. High chance of forgetting something (e.g. colors, triggers, ...) or making mistakes.

**Question:**
Is there a possibility to define that PART_ section so that it takes that part from the default style, so that I don't have to write down that default template anymore for that part but just use or show that part?

something like this:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar"
                 TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
      <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.RowSpan="3"
            CornerRadius="2"
            Background="#F0F0F0" />
    <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0"
                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                  Height="18"
                  Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand"
                  Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" />

<Rectangle Grid.Row="1" x:Name="OwnThingHERE" /> <!-- so that I can modify control template -->

     <ContentPresenter FOR PART_Track Grid.Row="1" /> <!-- but still 'bind' to the default -->

    <RepeatButton Grid.Row="3"
                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                  Height="18"
                  Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand"
                  Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

not sure if I explained it well, hopefully you'll understand.

Comment: Am I right, that the key here is binding? because you can do ControlTemplate={StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}

Comment: see this "<Rectangle Grid.Row="1" x:Name="OwnThingHERE" />" I want to add own controls at a certain position in the ScrollBar, but without having to add hundreds of lines for PART_'s that I don't want to change. Not sure if that answers your question?

Comment: As far as I know unfortunately there's no way to "modify" a control template in XAML - you always need to redefine it from top to bottom.